# Change sorting order to descending

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sorting, date, toolbar

In my website, sorting is in asc for all sorting option but if I select "Sort By Date" (created_at) I want it go sort on desc order. How do I do it? Also I have a theme installed. Below is the code used at present

```
                    <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                    </option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check for the key and change the sort direction on toolbar.

Something like this on the template file

> template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sort By: ')) ?>">
<?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
        <?php if($_key == 'created_at'): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php else: ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```